# Unable to stream data from MySQL to Postgres using Kafka

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka

I am trying Kafka for the first time and set up Kafka cluster using AWS MSK. The objective is to stream data from MySQL server to Postgresql.
I used debezium MySQL connector for source and Confluent JDBC connector for the sink.

MySQL config:

```
  "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
  "database.server.id": "1",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "transforms.unwrap.add.source.fields": "ts_ms",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "transforms": "unwrap",
  "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState"
```

After registering the Mysql connector, its status is "running" and capturing the changes being made in MySQL table and showing result in consumer console in the following format:

```
{"id":5,"created_at":1594910329000,"userid":"asldnl3r234mvnkk","amount":"B6Eg","wallet_type":"CDW"}
```

**My first issue:** in table "amount" column is of type "decimal" and contains numeric value but in consumer console why it is showing as alphanumeric value?

For Postgresql as target DB, I used JDBC sink connector, with following config:

```
"name": "postgres-connector-db08",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "topics": "mysql-cash.kafka_test.test",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx:5432/test?currentSchema=public",
  "connection.user": "xxxxxx",
  "connection.password": "xxxxxx",
  "insert.mode": "upsert",
  "auto.create": "true",
  "auto.evolve": "true"
```

After registering JDBC connector when I check status it gives an error:

```
{"name":"postgres-connector-db08","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"x.x.x.x:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"x.x.x.x:8083","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:561)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'postgres-connector-db08' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='mysql-cash.kafka_test.test',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1594909233389) with a HashMap value and null value schema.
 io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.RecordValidator.lambda$requiresValue$2(RecordValidator.java:83)
 io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:82)
 io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
 io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)
... 10 more
"}],"type":"sink"}
```

Why this error is coming? Is something I missed in the sink config?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html#data-mapping

```
The sink connector requires knowledge of schemas, so you should use a suitable converter e.g. the Avro converter that comes with Schema Registry, or the JSON converter with schemas enabled.
```

Since the JSON is plain (has no schema) and the connector is configured with `"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"` (JSON converter with schemas disabled), Avro converter should be set up with Schema Registry: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#applying-schema

Answer (score 0):

Answer about first issue. "Why decimal is dropped in alpha-numerical format?"

The conversion of decimal depends on decimal.handling.mode configuration.

> Specifies how the connector should handle values for DECIMAL and NUMERIC columns: precise (the default) represents them precisely using java.math.BigDecimal values represented in change events in a binary form; or double represents them using double values, which may result in a loss of precision but will be far easier to use. string option encodes values as formatted string which is easy to consume but a semantic information about the real type is lost.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/connectors/mysql.html#decimal-values

If there's no proper conversion configure for you, you can also create custom converter.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/development/converters.html

If lucky you can find some open-source converters to solve this issue.